# Why application hangs when using substring method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an application that pulls data from datebase:

```
db.books.find().sort({ _id: 1 }).limit(count).toArray(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        next(err, null);
    } else {
        next(null, results);
    }
});
```

each book has a description with long text, but I don't want to get the whole text for each book, So I decided to use `map` method for projecting the result so that I can get the number of characters for description:

```
db.books.find().sort({ _id: 1 }).limit(count)
    .map(function(item) {
        return {
            description: item.description.substring(0, 50),
            ,....
        }
    }).toArray(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            next(err, null);
        } else {
            next(null, results);
        }
});
```

but when I use `substring` method, the application hangs and I can't see the result.
Any idea?

Comment: Could you add a log statement before the return to log item.description and see if it does get logged?

Comment: try `item.description.slice(0, 50),`

Comment: @Ewald Thanks it helped :)

Comment: @SirwanAfifi - I'm always suspicious of data, I don't trust computers!  Great to hear you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad! some books didn't have description, they were `undefined`. I just solved it with a simple check:

```
description: item.description != undefined ? item.description.substring(0, 50) : 'no description',
```